# Event listener not working

Tags: android

Following is the code of `main activity class`. It sets content to `main.xml`, which includes a button `btn` . When this button is clicked, content is set to `pic.xml`, which has two buttons, `btn1` and `btn2`. When `btn1` is clicked, it should set the content back to `main.xml` but this is not happening.

```
package com.asin.amit;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;


import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class AsinActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private TextView tv ;
private VideoView myVideoView;
private Button btn;
private Button btn1;
private Button btn2;


@Override


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        String str= "/sdcard/DCIM/a.mp4";


        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);


        myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        myVideoView.setVideoPath(str);
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.start();


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myVideoView.pause();                         
                setContentView(R.layout.pic);
            }                                   
        });

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new ButtonListener());


    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        // handle any errors
        Log.e("HelloWorld", "1", e);  // log the error
        // Also let the user know something went wrong
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

class ButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
}
```

At the line `btn1.setOnClickListener(new ButtonListener());`  , logcat is saying `java.lang.NullPointerException`

What wrong am I doing ?

Comment: Are you certain there is a `Button` with _id_ `R.id.button1` at `R.layout.main`?

Comment: Also, try: if(myVideoView != null) myVideoView.pause(); or surround it with a try/catch

Comment: @K-ballo no, button1 is in pic.xml

Comment: @John Watson: Then how do you expect to _find_ it before its even there? It's `setContentView(R.layout.pic)` that puts it there...

Comment: @K-ballo Could you please tell me following: If we change the content using `setContentView` , does it destroys various objects and references created in the old content view ?

Comment: @John Watson: Yes. If you don't want that you can use `addContentView` or modify the layout programmatically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you have written, `When this button is clicked, content is set to pic.xml, which has two buttons, btn1 and btn2` your btn1 and btn2 are located in *R.layout.pic*, but your are trying to find them in *R.layout.main* layout by

`btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);`

`btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);`

You should set values to btn1 and btn2 variables (and onClickListener of course too) only after `setContentView(R.layout.pic)`, cause only then your layout will contain these buttons

Answer (score 0):

Using `setContentView()` more than once in an activity is (almost?) always a bad, bad idea. You're picking the button with the ID of R.id.button1 from your `main.xml` layout in your `onCreate()`, and setting a listener to that button. When you then call `setContentView(R.layout.pic)` that button is no longer valid. You would have to say `btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)` again after setting the content view. This is just a bad design because there are so many opportunities for it to break. Any reason you can't simply launch a new Activity with `pic.xml` as its content view when you click the button?

Comment: in this activity i am loading a video from sdcard. If i go to another activity, I have to come back and then the video has to be reloaded, i wanted to save this time. Also, in this activity an image is created, which is displayed in pic.xml. If I create new activity for pic.xml then don't you think passing the image object will consume a lot of time ?

Comment: can u suggest some ways , so that i do not have to reload the video ?